# FlotChart Real-time load from JSON do not render

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flot

I found real-time chart ([flotcharts.org](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/realtime/index.html)). Now I tried implemented load of data from JSON file.

Data in the file are (for **y** axis).

```
{
"data":[["1","3","5","7","9","11","2","8","6","15","3","18","14","9","51","13","6","18","16","3","15","32","17","11","1","23","5","17","9","1"]]
}
```

HTML and jQuery function are from example. I tried edit for ajax. Data for **x** axis I want to generate using variable **i** (below in the code).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <title>Flot Examples: Real-time updates</title>
 <link href="http://www.ondrej-vasko.cz/realtime/css/examples.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ondrej-vasko.cz/realtime/js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ondrej-vasko.cz/realtime/js/jquery.flot.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    // We use an inline data source in the example, usually data would
    // be fetched from a server

    var data = [],
        totalPoints = 300;

    function getRandomData() {
        $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.ondrej-vasko.cz/realtime/js/data_2.json",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json"
       }).success(function(data){
        //$('#placeholder').append(JSON.stringify(data) + '</br>');
        data.push(data);    
        });
       return false;

//          if (data.length > 0)
//              data = data.slice(1);

        // Do a random walk

//          while (data.length < totalPoints) {

//              var prev = data.length > 0 ? data[data.length - 1] : 50,
//                  y = prev + Math.random() * 10 - 5;
//
//              if (y < 0) {
//                  y = 0;
//              } else if (y > 100) {
//                  y = 100;
//              }

//              data.push(y);
//          }

        // Zip the generated y values with the x values

        var res = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
            res.push([i, data[i]])
        }

        return res;
    }

    // Set up the control widget

    var updateInterval = 30;
    $("#updateInterval").val(updateInterval).change(function () {
        var v = $(this).val();
        if (v && !isNaN(+v)) {
            updateInterval = +v;
            if (updateInterval < 1) {
                updateInterval = 1;
            } else if (updateInterval > 2000) {
                updateInterval = 2000;
            }
            $(this).val("" + updateInterval);
        }
    });

    var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", [ getRandomData() ], {
        series: {
            shadowSize: 0   // Drawing is faster without shadows
        },
        yaxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100
        },
        xaxis: {
            show: false
        }
    });

    function update() {

        plot.setData([getRandomData()]);

        // Since the axes don't change, we don't need to call plot.setupGrid()

        plot.draw();
        setTimeout(update, updateInterval);
    }

    update();

    // Add the Flot version string to the footer

    $("#footer").prepend("Flot " + $.plot.version + " &ndash; ");
});

</script>
```

```
<div id="header">
    <h2>Real-time updates</h2>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div class="demo-container">
    <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
  </div>
  <p>You can update a chart periodically to get a real-time effect by using a timer to insert the new data in the plot and redraw it.</p>
  <p>Time between updates: <input id="updateInterval" type="text" value="" style="text-align: right; width:5em"> milliseconds</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    Copyright &copy; 2007 - 2013 IOLA and Ole Laursen
</div>
```

After my editing do not work drawing data to graph. Can ask for help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be when you are pushing the data after the ajax call. Put an alert in the loop that returns "res" and make sure the data is in the correct format.

```
 var res = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        res.push([i, data[i]])
        *add Alert Here*
    }
```

Have a look at this example. http://jsfiddle.net/grgesxbt/3/

Answer (score 0):

Numerous problems at a quick glance:

1.) This:

```
var res = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    res.push([i, data[i]])
}
```

Needs to be **in** the `.success` callback function.  The way you have it now it'll execute before the AJAX call completes and data will still be `[]`.  Actually, you have a random `return false;` in there, so you never even hit the above code.

2.) Your AJAX return is an object with a "data" property that's an array of array of strings.  You then push this into another array. Very convoluted.  Rewrite the `.success` callback to be something like this:

```
.success(function(data){
    var array = data['data'][0];
    var res = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array .length; ++i) {
       res.push([i, parseFloat(array[i])])
    }
    return res;
});
```

3.) Notice the `parseFloat` above, that's important.  Your numbers are strings and flot won't like that.  That converts them to numeric data.  It would be better to fix your JSON file, then get rid of the `parseFloat`.  Actually if you can edit the JSON file, you can make it simply:

```
[1,3,5,7,9,11,2,8,6,15,3,18,14,9,51,13,6,18,16,3,15,32,17,11,1,23,5,17,9,1]
```

Then your `.success` callback becomes:

```
.success(function(data){
    var res = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
       res.push([i, data[i]])
    }
    return res;
});
```